Connecting 3x 0.91Oleds (Using a TCA9548A 8-channel multiplex) and 1 1.51 Inch Transperant SPI OLED
As the title suggests, I have an Arduino Nano connected to a multiplex (which is connected to 3x 0.91 OLEDs) and an 1.51 inch OLED connected through an SPI.
The problem is that they just refuse to work simultaneously - both work, I've tested them independently. However, when writing code for both, the second part to be initialized always fails. If I initialize the 1.51 OLED first it works and the 3x multiplex 0.91 fails and vise versa.
Here's my code:
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH_T 128
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT_T 64

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 32
#define OLED_RESET -1
#define OLED_ADDR 0x3C
#define TCA9548A_ADDR 0x70

#define OLED_MOSI 11
#define OLED_CLK 13
#define OLED_DC 8
#define OLED_CS 10
#define OLED_RESET_SPI 9

Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);
Adafruit_SSD1306 displayO(SCREEN_WIDTH_T, SCREEN_HEIGHT_T, OLED_MOSI, OLED_CLK, OLED_DC, OLED_RESET_SPI, OLED_CS);

void tcaSelect(uint8_t i) {
  if (i > 7) return;
  Wire.beginTransmission(TCA9548A_ADDR);
  Wire.write(1 << i);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);

  delay(100);
  
  if (!displayO.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3D)) {
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed for SPI OLED"));
    while (1);
  }
  displayO.display();
  delay(200);
  displayO.clearDisplay();
  displayO.drawPixel(10, 10, SSD1306_WHITE);
  displayO.display();
  delay(200);

  // Initialize I2C displays on the multiplexer
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    tcaSelect(i);
    delay(100);
    if (!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, OLED_ADDR)) {
      Serial.print(F("SSD1306 allocation failed for display on channel "));
      Serial.println(i + 1);
    } else {
      display.clearDisplay();
      display.setTextSize(1);
      display.setTextColor(SSD1306_WHITE);
      display.setCursor(0, 0);
      display.print(F("Hello World\nScreen "));
      display.print(i + 1);
      display.print(F("/3"));
      display.display();
      delay(1000);
    }
  }

  // Initialize SPI OLED display

}

void loop() {
  displayO.clearDisplay();
  displayO.setTextSize(1);
  displayO.setTextColor(SSD1306_WHITE);
  displayO.setCursor(0, 0);
  displayO.println(F("Hello, world!"));
  displayO.display();
  delay(2000);
}

In this example the 1.51 OLED (display0) initializes fine, however the other 3 displays fail.
If I switch some code around (placing display0 code below the display code) then the 3x OLEDs work and display0 fails.
I've been trying to solve this for ages and I got no idea what is causing this failure, please save me.

There may be pin conflicts arising somewhere. Make sure there are no conflicts between the SPI and I2C libraries.

i really got no idea, the multiplex sits on the A5 and A4 pins while the SPI sits on D9-D13 pins, theoretically it shouldnt be an issue (although i dont really know enough to be sure). every single check i ran (I2C port scans and the such) never returned any errors.
Eventually i gave up and went with adafruit for the Multiplex OLEDS and SSD1306Ascii for the SPI.
it is ugly, but it works, suboptimaly.

Are you not receiving the messages telling you that allocation failed?

Yeah, i do get the "Allocation failed" messages when it tries to initialize.

So, you've confirmed the failed-to-initialize in a comment that said:

Yeah, i do get the "Allocation failed" messages when it tries to initialize

When I build your code with what I have here for an environment:
Wire                 1.0     /home/user/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.7/libraries/Wire
SPI                  1.0     /home/user/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.7/libraries/SPI 
Adafruit GFX Library 1.11.9  /home/user/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_GFX_Library                       
Adafruit BusIO       1.15.0  /home/user/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_BusIO                             
Adafruit SSD1306     2.5.9   /home/user/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_SSD1306                           

it says:
Global variables use 587 bytes (28%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1461 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

By which "dynamic memory" doesn't mean what's conventionally meant by "dynamic memory" (dynamically allocated memory)  They're referring to SRAM (changeable thus "dynamic" memory) which includes both things like global variables but also normal string literals on the nano an other things.
The compiler knows that 587 bytes are flatly needed no matter what happens at runtime. You have 1461 remaining and are attempting to use one instance of Adafruit_SSD1306 for a 128x64 resolution display and second instance for multiple 128x32 resolution display. Using a single instance to control three displays is probably not something expected by Adafruit, but I'm not overly surprised that part at least appears to work.
The problem is that you are simply running out of memory, as the message you're receiving indicates. These are 1-bit-per-pixel display. So you need 128x32 and 128x64 bits at the same time. You can see this calculation being done in the Adafruit library. That's 128 * 4 and 128 * 8 bytes respectively. Or 512 bytes and 1024 bytes. Or 1536 bytes in total (just for the display buffer) So that already doesn't fit in 1461 bytes you have at start of runtime, nevermind the stack/local variables and some other things allocated at runtime (e.g Serial buffers) that are going to be in SRAM. So you are simply not going to be able to have both instances of Adafruit_SSD1306 for 128x32 and 128x64 resolutions at the same time still have enough memory left to function on an ATmege328P. Realistically you should probably get a larger chip.
But, you can try writing your code such that you only have one instance of either created at any given moment. Probably the simplest way to do this is to have functions that draw to the x32 and x64 displays and have the Adafruit_SSD1306 object be a local variable in that function, so that when the function exits after drawing a frame the dynamic memory it was using gets freed. The downside is you'd be re-initalizing the display on every frame on recreation of the Adafruit_SSD1306 object, but that may not be a problem. It may flicker or something to that effect. You'd need to test.
So your functions would take a form similar to:
void display_on_spi_x64() {
  Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH_T, SCREEN_HEIGHT_T, OLED_MOSI, OLED_CLK, OLED_DC, OLED_RESET_SPI, OLED_CS);
  if (!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC)) {
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed for SPI OLED"));
    while (1);
  }
  display.clearDisplay();
// various display.drawWhatever(); calls.
  display.display();
}


void display_on_i2c_x32(int display_i2c_mux_channel) {
  tcaSelect(display_i2c_mux_channel);
  Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);
  if (!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, OLED_ADDR)) {
    Serial.print(F("SSD1306 allocation failed for I2C display on channel "));
    Serial.println(display_i2c_mux_channel + 1);
    while (1);
  }
  display.clearDisplay();
// various display.drawWhatever(); calls.
  display.display();
}

I have not tested the above. It is only a guide.
So the Adafruit_SSD1306 instances only live while the function has been entered and die when the function ends. And when that happens the ram for the display buffer is freed. Nothing else is asked of the display, so it should retain the last image given to it even after the Adafruit_SSD1306 object dies when the function exits.
In theory the Adafruit_SSD1306 library could be modified so that you provide your own buffer of at least the minimum required size during begin() rather than allowing begin() to allocate it internally as the library currently does via malloc(). If you used your own buffer, you'd share that among the four instances of Adafruit_SSD1306 with the caveat that you need to re-render the entire frame when switching between devices. Though you're already subject to that restriction because of how you're using the single Adafruit_SSD1306 instance to control three I2C displays.
Another library (maybe u8g2) may already support this. Failing that, get an Arduino with more RAM. During usage of the 128x64 display, you will have less than 2048-1024-587 or 437 bytes of SRAM for stack/locals, Serial buffers and so on. It would not surprise me that a project using four displays like this would need more than 437 bytes to do all of the non-display related stuff. I believe u8g2 is able to use 512 bytes of ram when working with an 128x64 SSD1306 display through its multiple passes during the drawing phase. So, you may want to use u8g2 just to reclaim some SRAM even if you end up adopting the same strategy above of creating and destroying instances u8g2 displays object instead. Or again, get a bigger Arduino.
